# WAMP stopped loading Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, wampserver

Good day.
I am having problems with my WAMP. WAMP was previously loading my pages properly but some months ago I tried to use a keyboard shortcut to Refresh my tab on Chrome and when it refreshed, my Bootstrap stopped loading. Before I tried to use the shortcut, they were perfectly loading. However, when I connect to the internet, everything loads normally.

A point to note is that after it loads with it internet, it continues to load without the internet until I restart the system. It then requires the internet to load again.

I think this is the reason why my JavaScript doesn’t work every time.
enter image description here
My WAMP version is `3.0.6_x64_apache2.4.23_mysql5.7.14_php5.6.25-7.0.10.exe` and I know it’s not the latest version but the latest requires some VS libraries that I cannot get for now.

I have attached a screenshot of how `dashboard.php` loads before I connect to the internet. I have also attached the source code of `dashboard.php`

Is there anything I can do to salvage the situation? Do I have to host some of these libraries locally?
Any form of help would be appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation

[image: Screenshot of dashboard.php before i connect to the internet]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Inventory Management System</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <?php 
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    include_once("./templates/header.php"); 
    
    ?>

    
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mx-auto">
                  <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" style="width:60%;" src="./images/user.png" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Profile Info</h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp;</i>John Doe</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-lock">&nbsp;</i>Admin</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp;</i>Last Login: xxxx-xx-xx</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit">&nbsp;</i>Edit Profile</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- It's in the div above that you will put all other things like drugs expiring, things -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="jumbotron" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                    <h1>Welcome Admin,</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i7a
                        ve1ay/n4842/szw110/szh110/hoc00f/hbw0/hfc000/cf100/hgr0/f
                        acf90/mqcfff/mql6/mqw2/mqd74/mhcfff/mhl6/mhw1/mhd74/mmcf90/m
                        ml4/mmw1/mmd74/hwm2/hhcfff/hmcfff" 
                        frameborder="0" width="110" height="110"></iframe>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Orders</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Create new orders from the warehouse and print invoices</p>
                                <!-- If you wish put the ahref for modal buttons here -->
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">New Orders</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Users</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Create new orders from the warehouse and print invoices. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#users_form" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Categories</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Manage Drug Categories. Add Parent and Sub Categories</p>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categories_form" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Brands</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Here you can manage your brand and you add new brand</p>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#brands_form" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Products</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Manage products and you add new products. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#products_form" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        //Category form
        include_once("./templates/categories.php");
    ?>
    <?php
        //Category form
        include_once("./templates/brands.php");
    ?>
    <?php
        //Brand form
        include_once("./templates/products.php");
    ?>
    <?php
        //Product form
        include_once("./templates/suppliers.php");
    ?>
    <?php
        //Users form
        include_once("./templates/users.php");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ___Small Point___ WAMP does not load the javascript libraries, the browser does

Comment: ___Also notice___ That `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com` is not on your local system. Without a connection to the internet that library and the others that are not on your PC will not load

Comment: Out of interest what was the ___keyboard shortcut to Refresh my tab___ that you used

Comment: try to use devtools `Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux)`

Comment: It sounds like you are getting the js code and css from the browser cache, which your browser is set to clear when you close it

Comment: PS, On WampServer or come to that any Apache system. When developing a site, create a Virtual Host for it. This will ensure that when you come to release the site to a real web server things that are DocumentRoot specific will still work. See [The need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) and [Create and add a Virtual Host](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746) its been made as simple as possible

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. Please how do i hostall those Bootstrap libraries locally? Also i have forgotten the keyboard shortcut i used. Lastly i created a Virtual Host with the instructions provided on the link and when i tried to follow the link from the WAMP Icon, it came up with `This site can’t be reached. pharmacy’s server IP address could not be found.` (pharmacy is the name of the Virtual Host). Please what do i do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, also if i am getting the JS code and CSS from browser cache, what do i do to fix it? By hosting the libraries locally?

Comment: Stay connected to the internet if you want to continie linking to those resources from the interent, otherwise host them on your site

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I figured it out myself. First, as @RiggsFolly suggested, the reason the Bootstrap was not loading was because i wasn't connected to the internet. If you want Bootstrap to load without the internet, host it locally. I guess that's pretty obvious.

Secondly If your browser isn't rendering your JavaScript look closely, your syntax may be faulty. In my case it was an extra curly brace. If you have fixed that and your JavaScript is not still rendering, you might have to use Developer Options on Chrome - `Command + Option + C (Mac) or Control + Shift + C (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS).`

1. Navigate to the `Sources` tab. You should see your File directory (Make sure `Page` and not `Filesystem` is selected)
2. Locate your JavaScript file in its directory and click on it (It should display on a mini text-editor there on the browser)
3. If you look closely, you might see that not all your JavaScript code is being rendered by your browser. If you have added some new blocks of code to your JavaScript file and you didn't see it updated in that mini text-editor then you might have to clear your cookies.
4. Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up > Restore settings to their original defaults > Reset settings. Among other things, this will clear your cookies and disable all your extensions on Chrome. You should first try to clear the cookies of that particular site first.
5. Reload the page and your JavaScript should render properly now.

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks for the help.